# How to write dynamic if else condition in where clause inside stored procedure?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

In my ColdFusion file previously i was using inline query like

```
SELECT *
FROM   XYZTABLE
WHERE       S.price > 0
                AND O.ORIGQUOTEDATE >= <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" value="#getParam('startDate')#">
                AND O.ORIGQUOTEDATE <= <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" value="#getParam('endDate')#">
                <cfif len(getParam("lowerPriceLimit")) neq 0 and len(getParam("upperPriceLimit")) neq 0 >
                    AND O.order_total BETWEEN #getParam("lowerPriceLimit")# AND #getParam("upperPriceLimit")#
                <cfelseif len(getParam("lowerPriceLimit")) neq 0 and len(getParam("upperPriceLimit")) eq 0 >
                    AND O.order_total >= #getParam("lowerPriceLimit")#
                <cfelseif len(getParam("lowerPriceLimit")) eq 0 and len(getParam("upperPriceLimit")) neq 0 >
                    AND O.order_total <= #getParam("upperPriceLimit")#       
                </cfif>
```

Now i want to convert this query to stored procedure.

I have written like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE quoteConversionByCategory(
    @startDate date,
    @endDate date,
    @lowerPriceLimit numeric(18),
    @upperPriceLimit numeric(18)
    )
    AS
    BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM   XYZTABLE
        WHERE   /*Not sure how to write*/
END
```

Is the only way is to create a dynamic sql string and execute it or is there any other way
exist?

How to handle these conditons?

```
<cfif len(getParam("bool")) eq 1>
AND (O.wcs_status_id = 9 or (O.wcs_status_id = 1 and   datediff(hour,O.origquotedate,O.order_date) > 4) )
<cfelse>
 AND O.wcs_status_id IN (9,1)       
</cfif>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with just using an `OR` statement in your `WHERE` criteria:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE quoteConversionByCategory(
@startDate date,
@endDate date,
@lowerPriceLimit numeric(18),
@upperPriceLimit numeric(18)
)
AS
BEGIN
SELECT * 
FROM   XYZTABLE
WHERE price > 0
    AND ORIGQUOTEDATE >= @startDate
    AND ORIGQUOTEDATE <= @endDate
    AND (Order_Total >= @lowerPriceLimit OR @lowerPriceLimit = 0) 
    AND (Order_Total <= @upperPriceLimit OR @upperPriceLimit = 0)
```

Depending on how your passing the lower and upper limits, you may need to alter the `OR` criteria above.  For example:

```
(Order_Total <= @upperPriceLimit OR @upperPriceLimit IS NULL)
```

Comment: I need to check with order_total only if it is not an empty string or not null. If null or "" I do not want these conditions.Will ur query work like this

Comment: You should be able handle this with default values of your input parameters.

Comment: @user3427540 -- yes indeed, that's what the `OR` is for in the criteria.  The key is the parentheses.  Either Order_Total >= SomeValue `OR` SomeValue is `NULL`.

Comment: @sgeddes: I have added a new condtion in the question , how to handle that?

Comment: You add a new input parameter and do the same sort of thing as was done with order total.

Comment: @user3427540 -- the same way :)  Add a new parameter to your procedure for bool (is that really your column name?) and then make sure your parentheses are correct.  Something like AND ((@bool = 1 AND Yadi) OR (@bool <> 1 AND Yada)).  Give it a try!

Comment: @sgeddes yes done. Thanks a lot. Previously I was trying to prepare a dynamic sql string.I think doing this way is more elegant.